# android application checking user role with database

Tags: android, xampp

First of all i would like to say that im very new to developing android and right now im just following a tutorial on how to develop an application that also uses login.

i have already finished to check if the user exist and the app will display a status saying if the login is a success.

now i would like to check if the user has an administrator role or a user role which is saved in the database.

tqvm in advanced.

below is the coding

```
1. MainActivity.java

package com.example.user.mysqldemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText UsernameEt, PasswordEt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        UsernameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        PasswordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    }

    public void OnLogin(View view){
        String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
        String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
        String type = "login";


        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
    }

}

2.BackgroundWorker.java

public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://ipaddress/foldername/login.php";
    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `login.php` script must return the value of the login status and also the role of the person in the response.
A JSON structure like this,

```
{
    "status" = 1,   //0 or 1 depending on login result
    "role" = 1      //a number based on the user type
}
```

Then you can parse this JSON result in `onPostExecute` and display the results.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(result);
    int status = jso.getInt("status")
    int role = jso.getInt("role")
    if(status == 1){
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();

        if(role == 0){
            //User
        } else if(role == 1){
            //Admin
        }
    } else{
        //Login Failed
    }
}
```